# Enable Rsyslog with TLS to Graylog2

Tags: rsyslog, ca, graylog2, graylog

My problem is that I cannot get logs from my remote app to log to a Graylog2 input using TLS. The remote app was logging just fine before I attempted to enable TLS with self-signed certs so I am pretty sure I just have a config problem

Here is some background. First, I created some self-signed certs following these steps:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out CA.key 2048
$ openssl req -x509 -new -nodes -key CA.key -sha256 -days 3650 -out rootCA.crt
$ openssl genrsa -out graylog-server.key 2048
$ openssl req -new -key graylog-server.key -out graylog-server.csr
$ openssl x509 -req -in graylog-server.csr -CA rootCA.crt -CAkey CA.key -CAcreateserial -out graylog-server.crt -days 3640 -sha256
```

source: https://gist.github.com/fntlnz/cf14feb5a46b2eda428e000157447309

Where I filled in the DNS name for the graylog server in the graylog-server.crt

I then imported the rootCA.crt to the keystore on the graylog server:

```
$ keytool -importcert -keystore ./graylog-cacerts -alias graylogRootCaCert -file rootCa.crt
```

Then, I log into the Graylog web interface and I reconfigure the input fields to this:

```
port: 51xx
TLS Cert File: /path/to/certs/graylog-server.csr
TLS Private Key File: /path/to/certs/graylog-server.key
Enable TLS: True
TLS Client authentication: Optional
TLS Client Auth Trusted Certs: /path/to/certs*
```

all the created certs are in the `/path/to/certs/` directory which is owned by the graylog. All keys are read only.

The remote app running on Ubuntu 16.04 has an rsyslog config that looks like this:

```
$ cat 60-remote-rsyslog.conf

$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls

$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/ssl/graylog/rootCA.pem
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1 # run driver in TLS-only mode
#$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer graylog.name.com

. @@graylog.name.com:51XX;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

As for the rsyslog.conf on the server, it is using all the defaults. I have seen a solution where the TLS is set up through rsyslog directly and then Graylog picks up the logs from there, but this is not ideal for my application. We need to use the inputs. That solution is here: 
https://serverfault.com/questions/807651/forwarding-logs-from-rsyslog-to-graylog-over-tls

I have tried following the steps in these links, but it is still not working: 
https://community.graylog.org/t/rsyslog-over-tls/263/4
https://community.graylog.org/t/encrypt-traffic-from-rsyslog/5649

I expect that the logs will come from the client TLS secured into the configured input. What happens is the logs do not arrive in the input, and the graylog-server logs do not have any errors to speak of.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue. 
 The lack of detailed connection error logs for graylog configured TLS inputs is annoying when things don't work...

Remember that Graylog needs PKCS8 configured key's so you may be looking at a PKCS8 key compatibility issue.  Start with plain.key's for initial setup and troubleshooting...

## Convert existing key to pkcs8

```
sudo openssl pkcs8 -in my.key -topk8 -nocrypt -out my.key.plain.pem
sudo openssl pkcs8 -in my.key.plain.pem -topk8 -out my.key.encrypted.pem -passout pass:secret
```

My Centos Box has rsyslog and /etc/rsyslog.d/rsyslog-tls.conf is configured like so:

```
# certificate files
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/my-CA.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server-01.domain.com.crt.pem
$DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/server-01.domain.com.key.plain.pem
# set up the action
$DefaultNetstreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode x509/name
$ActionSendStreamDriverPermittedPeer *.domain.com
*.* @@(o)graylog.domain.com:6514
```

## My Graylog SyslogTCP(TLS) Input

```
tls_cert_file: /etc/graylog/ssl/shadowCA/graylog.domain.com/graylog.domain.com.crt.pem
tls_client_auth: optional
tls_client_auth_cert_file: <empty>
tls_enable: true
tls_key_file: /etc/graylog/ssl/shadowCA/graylog.domain.com/graylog.domain.com.key.plain.pem
```

## Troubleshooting TLS with OpenSSL S_CLIENT

PS. A helpful troubleshooting step is to ensure the input is properly configured for TLS, LISTENING, ANSWERING, and ACCEPTING MESSAGES

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:1514 -tls1_2 -tlsextdebug
```

## -tlsextdebug  allows you to type test messages to graylog over TLS.

Comment: That is a great test. I was able to run that command and see a log message in my graylog console. So that may rule out my thought that I have a certificate problem.

Comment: Posted in graylog community also: 
https://community.graylog.org/t/enable-rsyslog-with-tls-to-graylog2/10650

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of this was that I had not installed the additional packages needed for `rsyslog` to send TLS logs. After I installed them, it worked like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Follow original documentation
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls_cert_summary.html
install certtool (like openssl, but rsyslog remends it) and gtls driver for rsyslog
Ubuntu

```
sudo apt install -y gnutls-bin rsyslog-gnutls
```

example of rsyslog include

```
#certificates

DefaultNetstreamDriverCAFile="/etc/rsyslog.d/ca.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverCertFile="/etc/rsyslog.d/machine- cert.pem"
DefaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile="/etc/rsyslog.d/machine-key.pem"


# make gtls driver the default
$DefaultNetStreamDriver gtls
$ActionSendStreamDriverMode 1   # run driver in TLS-only mode
$ActionSendStreamDriverAuthMode anon

#replace node with actual central log server
*.* @@glsrv:10514;RSYSLOG_SyslogProtocol23Format
```

use scripts to generate certificates and keys
https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/tutorials/tls_cert_script.html